# #! won't make linux run an interpreter

Tags: linux, scripting

Here's the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

CODES = {}
puts "ok"
```

Under `root` user everything is fine:

```
# ./test.rb
ok
```

When `munin`'s default interpreter is `/bin/false` nothing is happpening:

```
# su munin -c ./test.rb
```

When default interpreter is `/bin/sh`, it is always being used:

```
# su munin -c ./test.rb
./test.rb: line 3: CODES: command not found
```

Why under `munin` user Linux ignores the interpreter line from the script, while under `root` it works as usual?

**Update**. Finally it just started to work without any intentional fix from me.

Answer (score 1):

`#!` is interpreted by shell and if you not specify what shell you need by `-s SHELL` then it is default shell - `/bin/false` in you case. And `false` not understand `#!` syntax (in fact - not read you script at all). Use `-s /bin/sh` with su and it will work as you want.

Comment: Munin itself will run the script with default interpreter. When default for its user is `/bin/sh` it tries to run the Ruby script as his own script.

Comment: @PavelKoryagin This part I don't understand - only good explanation for me is space between # and ! or on start of line, but it is obviously not a case because it works without su. Anyway - glad to hear it works for you now.